# Re-route laptop dc power jack to a usb port

Tags: laptop, usb, power-supply, power-jack

Because many times my laptop powers off after some movement around the power jack,
I thought I would re-route the internal power cables that ends up in the DC power jack, and fit them into a USB. Then cut the power cord, from the power supply and fit it in a male USB so it will, probably get a better fit. Has anyone tried doing this? Any suggestions?

PS: I think some Lenovo G500 I have seen using such way as factory default.

Comment: USB cables can't handle the type of voltages your battery is expecting.  What you describe won't work.

Comment: I see, you have a point there. Have you seen the charging port of a lenovo g500 for example, do you think that isnt "just" a usb port ?

Comment: I can guarantee you it isn't a USB port.

Comment: I'd have a fire extinguisher at the ready...

Comment: The port on the Lenovo G500 is a normal barrel plug.  You are probably referring to the plug on the newer *G50*.  However, that plug is **nothing at all like a USB port**, it's just approximately the same size.  It is, in fact, just a flattened version of the old barrel plug on the previous models.

Answer (score 1):

First, powering your laptop over USB itself is likely to be impossible. Most modern laptops that I've seen take between 50 and 100 watts to charge, but USB itself doesn't typically allow more than 10W per port.  Additionally, your laptop's USB circuitry likely won't accept power anyway.

If you really want to physically redirect one of your USB ports to replace the power plug, I have a much better idea for you.  *Just replace the broken power plug with a new one that works!* It's going to be much safer than trying to retrofit a USB port, and replacement power sockets are available for most laptops.  All you need is a soldering iron, a steady hand, and a bunch of screw drivers (which are all the same things you would need if you wanted to do this to your USB port too).